# Make position absolute child fit width and height of parent that overflows due to a different child with min-height and min-width

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/petermirmo/pen/eQpWXN

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling1">
  </div>
  <div class="sibling2">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:auto;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.sibling1{
  min-height: 4000px;
  min-width: 4000px; 
  width: 100%;
}
.sibling2{
  background-color:orange;

  position: absolute;

  top:0; 
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;

}
```

Trying to make the sibling2 div fit the entire .parent div . I have tried overflow: overlay; position: relative; to the .parent. Also adding display: table to .parent and display: table-row; to child; If you have any ideas let me know! Please look at the codepen, it will make the situation more clear :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the parent `inline-block`. By default it's a block element so it width is limited to its parent width and you are having an overflow. Using `inline-block` will make it fit its content.

```css
.parent {
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
  /*overflow:auto; useless as the overflow is now on an upper level*/
  display:inline-block;
}
.sibling1{
  min-height: 4000px;
  min-width: 4000px; 
}
.sibling2{
  background-color:orange;

  position: absolute;

  top:0; 
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  /*useless
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling1">
  </div>
  <div class="sibling2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I add width 100% to .parent this stops working. Do you know why?

Comment: @petermir 100% means 100% of its parent and the parent is the body so you limit the width of the parent and it will no more fit its content. it's exactly like making the element block element ... that's why the solution is to use inline-block because the width of inline block is not 100% but it's the content width

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. That makes perfect sense.